# How to leave out the last column when calculating the width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the first tr
    var firstRow = $('.header');

    //Clone the first row
    firstRow.clone().attr('class', 'fixedHeader').prependTo('#ResultsTable');

    //Match the th widths of the cloned tr
    firstRow.find('th').each(function (i) {
        var thWidth = $(this).width();

        $('.fixedHeader th').eq(i).css({
            width: thWidth
        });
    });
});
```

The code takes the first row (header) and duplicates and attached to the table and make it fixed so the table scroll and the header stays in place.

How can I modify the code so it duplicates every column of the header except the last.

CSS:

```
.fixedHeader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    background-color: #dce9f9;
    border-top: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    width: 97.5%;
}
.gLine {
     display: none;
}
```

So if I have 7 columns in a table I would like it to only duplicate 6 columns. The reason being is I am hiding the last column at runtime so it calculates the header and displays a white space at the end.

ASP.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="BookingResults" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="commHdr" Text="Show Guideline" CssClass="sg" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnShow3" CssClass="btnSearch3" Text="VIEW" OnClientClick="javascript:test(this);return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic" HeaderText="Topic" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-CssClass="tTitle"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Specialty" HeaderText="Specialty" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Provider">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <div id="dvHide" class="clsHide">
                       <asp:Label ID="lblEllipsis" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Provider") %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Provider") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-CssClass="sumM">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Guideline" HeaderText="Guideline" ItemStyle-CssClass="gLine" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gLine" />
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Does `firstRow.clone().attr('class', 'fixedHeader').find("th:last").remove()` work?

Comment: @Huangism Where should I add the line or doesn't matter?

Comment: Actually I am now unsure what you want at the end, is http://jsfiddle.net/92y5grbk/ what you want? The headers you see is the fixedHeader class items

Comment: I understand. I updated my question. I am generating a column (header and body) and hiding it in the front end because I will be using the text in each row for the column for some other function. I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice`.

```
firstRow.find('th').slice(0, -1).each(function () {
  ...
});
```

Comment: The `width` is still calculated based on the last column. :/

Comment: I am just not sure what to include... Should I include snapshot of the generated HTML?

Comment: I think the OP wants to remove the last column before doing the `each` so when the width is calculated, it gives the correct value. Let say there are 5 columns, but we only want the first 4 so when calculated, the width returns 25% instead of 20%. Basically the clone should have 1 less column than the original (the last column removed)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zaweho/1/edit?html,js,output Here is the code in action with a little demo.

Comment: @BillCriswell I have no doubt it should be working :) Mine is not for some reason :/

Answer (score 2):

You might try `firstRow.find('th').not(':last').each(...)` or maybe `firstRow.find('th:not(:last)').each(...)` to condense it to one statement.

Comment: I am testing it out now. Thank you. Update: That didn't work. It still shows up :/